# Enable Google Photos Android backup from web

Tags: remote-access, google-photos

I'm trying to enable Google Photos backup from web like accessing to my account in photos.google.com and switching somewhere the backup to ON but there's no such "switch".

Anyone know how can I turn on the backup on my Android device to Google Photos without access to the device, only from web? I think i can send an app from play.google.com to the device and that app enables me to turn on that "switch" remotely but I don't  know if it exist.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot turn it on without having your device because if you try to turn on from the web, Google will not be able to know which device to be backed up. So you have to download Google Photos application from Google play store and it will automatically turned on when you download and install it.